# Is is possible to create body armour that can withstand being shot ten times?

Tags: warfare, armors, firearms

So in video games, there is there armor that is gun-resistant. I know there is real-world armor that could take one shot but is there one that could take, say, ten? Is there an example of this?

Comment: ten shots from what?

Comment: I feel like there are too many variables here. Ten shots from a pistol, or ten shots from a machine gun? Ten shots in the exact same spot, or ten shots spread across the entirety of the armor?

Comment: Video games can alter kinetic energy and momentum for dramatic effect. The impact of a single 7.62mm round against your properly-functioning body armor won't kill you, but is still very likely to knock you down...and *hurt*.

Comment: Most existing body armor can already take being shot 10 times, so long as it's not in the exact same spot...

Comment: how thick and heavy can the armor be? And what materials are available? and what kind of projectiles are going to hit it? at what speed? This question needs to add details to be answered. VTC

Comment: In 1879 armor worn by [Ned Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armour_of_the_Kelly_gang), made from plough steel survived being hit a ["number of times"](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=ned+kelly+armour&atb=v246-1&ia=web) by [Martini-Henry bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.577/450_Martini%E2%80%93Henry)

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else it really depends on what you're shooting it with and the type of armor (which will be dictated by what you're shooting at it).

Currently military standards designate armor from level 3 soft and level 4 plate rigged armor. Level 3 soft is basically for handgun rounds, and it can stop multiple rounds in it's specifications. Plenty of YouTube gun channels that shoot the same kevlar panel over and over and over. You can even blast through it with a rifle round and it will still catch handgun bullets so long as the material is good enough shape.

Level 4 rigid armor is rated to stop certain rifle caliber rounds,  and even then it's a limited selection. Armor rated to stop dedicated armor piercing rounds are going to be too heavy to use realistically. Bullets always have the advantage against armor however some of these heavy hitting calibers are not terribly common.

Level 4 armor is made of either steel or ceramic composite panels. Steel will stop hand guns rounds all day and generally keep taking abuse up until it fails. Ceramic armor is designed to shatter when absorbing the impact.

Then there is the consideration of the squishy meat mech in the armor. Just because the bullet is caught , doesn't mean all that energy goes away. Most of it will be absorbed across either your kevlar or steel plate, or if ceramic it explodes. Some of that energy still goes into. Kind of like a car crash, the airbag and deformation eats up the worst of the energy but it's still gonna hurt. In fact with plate armor in the late medieval period when it was still be used , war hammers and maces were used not so much to crack the armor open but bludgeon the soft meaty mech under neath it. Let's say you have armor rated to stop a 20mm anti-tank round from piercing (kinetic penetrator no fancy HE rounds) the armor. You're still getting hit with with like 6-10k joules of energy. Even if your armor doesn't get a hole in it and you don't get a hole in you, your organs will be liquefied.

Also it depends on where you get shot. Usually rifle plate only covers the torso / the most central organs. There isn't rifle rated plate really for limbs or helmets / head protection. So gotta keep that in mind too.

Also onto the head. The head is going to be the most vulnerable part. First is dealing with all that excess kinetic energy. I've seen some footage of a helmet rate for 12 gauge slugs with a ballistic gel / glass skull target. The energy transfer from the 44 Magnum and 12 gauge slug would most likely fracture you're skull. Then there is dealing with essentially whip lash. That bullet is gonna snap ur head back. Do it fast enough and it will break or severely injure the neck. Not to mention you're brain is gonna ping pong ball off around your skull.

So a couple of scenarios that realistic enough. Shot multiple times with a handgun with soft armor but the person getting shot is gonna feel like Mike Tyson hit him a few times. Or if they're wearing rifle plate and get shot with pistol or a much weaker round than the armor is rated for.

Comment: "Level 4 armor is made of either steel or ceramic" - it appears like OP is looking for Level IV non-ceramic body armor - but I am aware of only ceramic-based designs. Do you have any references to the steel-based ones?

Comment: Obviously there is a market for armor with retro rockets.  How fast could such devices (essentially outward facing explosive bolts arrayed in various directions) respond to a detected impact?

Comment: Ar500 steel. Its often covered

Comment: Ar500 steel plate. Usually coated in a rubber like substance to catch fragmentss.

Comment: Level 4 Ar500 armor is still ceramic: https://www.ar500armor.com/level-4-body-armor.html

Answer (score 0):

People can survive being shot many times by arrows and bullets in their lifetime even if they never wear any armor, if they are lucky enough.

On May 30, 1806, future president Andrew Jackson and Thomas Dickinson dueled.  Dickinson's shot hit Jackson in the chest near his heart.  Jackson remained standing and carefully aimed his pistol and fired.  Dickinson was wounded in the abodomen and died a few hours later. The bullet in Jackson's chest was just an inch from his heart and was never removed, and caused Jackson a lot of pain in later life.  Jackson died 39 years later in 1845, aged 78, and his wound possibly
shortened his life by months or years.

At Fort Fisher in 1865, General Uriah Galusha Pennypacker, who had been seriously wounded several times in the war, was shot so badly that when the wound reopened later in life it killed him - 51 years later. As Pennypacker lay montionless on the ground, he saw his men lynch the Rebel who had shot him.

In the 16 December 2014 Peshawar school massacre, terrorists killed 149 people including 132 kids aged 8 to 18. 12 year old Waleed khan was shot six times in the face, once in the hand, and once in the leg and just barely managed to survive.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Peshawar_school_massacre[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Peshawar_school_massacre%5B1%5D)

[https://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcthree/article/a3358a8c-96e7-4a9a-adc0-8d14d3465453[2]](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcthree/article/a3358a8c-96e7-4a9a-adc0-8d14d3465453%5B2%5D)

According to *A Complete Guide to Heraldry*, Arthur Charles Fox-Davies, page 591:

> At the Battle of Naseby Dr. Edward Lake fought bravely for the King, and in the service of his Majesty received no less than sixteen wounds. At the end of the battle, when his left arm was useless, he put the bridle of his horse between his teeth and still fought on. The quartering of augmentation given to him was: "Gules, a dexter arm embowed in armour holding in the hand a sword erect all proper, thereto affixed a banner argent charged with a cross between sixteen escutcheons of the field, on the cross a lion of England." The sixteen shields upon the banner typify his sixteen wounds.

[https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry/Chapter_37#589[3]](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Complete_Guide_to_Heraldry/Chapter_37#589%5B3%5D)

Dr. Lake died in 1674, 29 years after the battle.

These few examples, out of many, show that a person can be wounded many times in their life, and sometimes many times in a single incident, and still survive. In some cases a person can function and still fight despite having been wounded at least once in that incident.

Most armor designs will protect someone better than no armor, though it is possible that some forms of armor and some times of projectiles will produce worst wounds than no armor at all.

So it is possible for someone shot in the wrong place by a sufficiently powerful bullet to die instantly, whether they are wearing armor or not.  It is possible for someone to be fatally wounded but remain conscious long enough to kill the person who shot them.  It is possible for someone with or without armor to be shot several times and still function well enough to fight. It is possible for someone wearing the best type of armor to be disabled by a single shot.

So there is real life armor which can under certain circumstances, enable the wearer to sometimes survive and function and keep on fighting for a while after being shot several times by some types of bullets.

So the video games mentioned are not totally unrealistic, though I expect they greatly exaggarate the protective effectiveness of armor.

Answer (score 0):

**Viscoelastic armor**

The example is silly putty.  On receiving a sudden force, it shatters, the force being absorbed in breaking and heating the material.  This is true for ceramic body armor.  The viscoelastic armor however flows under no or gentle force.  After being shattered by the bullet, the armor will reconstitute itself.

Possible a charge thru the armor encourages it to flow back into position, or this is encouraged by the topology of the armor - there are protrusions that are "wetted" at a rest state.

Such armor could be shot many times if given time between hits to reconstitute.  It could not be shot in the same place many times in rapid succession.